# How can i terminate 'find' after the first match?

Tags: bash, grep, find

I am using find in a while loop.
it takes a list of ips in ip.txt, searches for the ip in a directory of files and then writes the name of the file that each IP was found in to a file called results.res

I want find to stop and move onto the next ip after each succesful find.

My current script is:

```
while read ip; do
    find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -not -name ips.txt -not -name results.res -print0  | xargs -0 grep "$ip" >> results.res
done < ips.txt
```

I have researched other answers on the website and found that using

```
-print -quit
-print | head -n 1
```

stops find after the first succesful find, however because i'm using a while loop this does not work, can anybody suggest a working solution?

Comment: Your problem is interesting, but if you want just to get rid of it, you could probably use just `grep -rlm1 "$ip" | head -n1 >> results.txt` instead of `find`.

Answer (score 2):

```
while IFS= read -r ip; do
  find . -maxdepth 1 \
         -type f \
         ! -name ips.txt \
         ! -name results.res \
         -exec grep -lwFe "$ip" {} \; \
         -quit
done < ips.txt > results.res
```

Would read each line of the `ips.txt` file into the `$ip` variable and go through the files matching the `find` criteria (in no particular order), reporting the first file which contains `$ip` as a `F`ixed string and `w`ord delimited. `-quit` is invoked when `-exec` succeeds which is when `grep` returns a *true* exit status when a match is found.

Answer (score 1):

The way your script is currently written, it will run `find`, then run `grep` for each file it finds, for every `ip` it finds in `ips.txt`.

You do not need to run `find` each time to get the same list of files, so take that out of the `while` loop and assign it to a variable.  You also do not need to run `grep` for each file you find, you can search them all in one command.  Now that you have the list of files, you can do a `grep` for each `ip` and only return the first match.  So the script would look something like this now:

```
files=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -not -name ips.txt -not -name results.res)
while read ip; do
    grep --with-filename --max-count=1 "$ip" $files | head -n 1 >> results.res
done < ips.txt
```

This will `grep` through each file from the `find` command for each `ip` in `ips.txt` and should put in lines that contain each IP address, and the first file in which it was found into `results.res`.

EDIT:

After some testing, there does seem to be a better way as the previous code does not handle filenames with spaces or odd characters at all.  So I am going to get rid of `find` as it seems unnecessary here.

You are planning on `grep`ing through all files in the current directory except `results.res` and `ips.txt`, so you could use `grep` without find at all:

```
while read ip; do
    grep --with-filename --max-count=1 --exclude={results.res,ips.txt} "$ip" * | head -n 1 >> results.res
done < ips.txt
```

Comment: OP does the smart thing in using `-print0 | xargs -0` for processing filenames; you should too.

Comment: Using `find` within the `while` loop as in OP's question seemed terribly inefficient if they only want the first match.  If you have an answer using `find` with `-print0 | xargs -0` that fits the OP's desired behavior I will upvote it.  Since file processing seems unnecessary in this particular instance, I have made an update that does not do it.

Comment: I did not say you had to use `find` within the loop. `find ... -print0 > files; while ... do xargs -0a files grep ...`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, however the number of files in the direcrtory i am searching through is too large for grep and i receive '/bin/grep: Argument list too long'. This is why i used find in the first place (sorry should of mentioned this). i their a solution without grep?